# progressDialog and wait for a signal

Tags: android

I want look for my GPS signal, while it's looking for it I have a ProgressDialog, but, it showed when the task is finished:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    DialogInterface.OnCancelListener dialogCancel = new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "no encotnrada", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    };

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "buscando", "gps", true, true, dialogCancel);

    while(currentLocation == null){

    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}
```

in run() I look for my currentLocation value.

How can I wait for this signal in order to show the dialog?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used GPS, and the GPS process is not running on the same process that running your app.
so there must be something wrong with your code, the `GPS listener` fires a `location` object if signal is found, so you can `dismiss` your `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: how can i do it?

Yours is the one I want to accept, but I don't know how

Comment: click over the `√` on the left of my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's shown at the end, because you're looping in the main thread. Instead you should do the waiting in the asynctask or another thread - then the dialog will be shown. In the onPostExecute of the asynctask you can start your other thread.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    final WaitForIt waiter = new WaitForIt();

    DialogInterface.OnCancelListener dialogCancel = new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "no encotnrada", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            waiter.cancelWait();
        }

    };

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "buscando", "gps", true, true, dialogCancel);

    waiter.execute();
}

private class WaitForIt extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     private synchronized boolean cancelled = false;
     public void cancelWait() { cancelled = true; }

     protected Void doInBackground() {
         while(!cancelled) {
             if (gps signal available)
                 break;
         }
     }

     protected void onPostExecute() {
         pd.dismiss();
         Thread thread = new Thread(MyActivity.this);
         thread.start();
     }
}
```